# Keeping Android quiet at night

Tags: notifications, silent-mode

I'd like my Android device to keep quiet during the night, no alerts for mails and talk messages, only calls and of course, the wake-up alarm. How can I do it?

Comment: Don't you wake up from vibrate? Then you'll still wake up from calls, but won't be bothered with anything else

Answer (score 16):

Timeriffic is fantastic for this purpose.  You can get the latest version from the app's [Google Play store page](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alfray.timeriffic), or you can get an older version from [f-droid.org](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=timeriffic&fdid=com.alfray.timeriffic).

Comment: It is also free

Comment: I'm using this one and so far it's working great. I might give Sweet Dreams for Android a try.

Answer (score 9):

In Marshmallow you don't need to install any apps as this is a native feature:

- Go to `settings` > `Sound & notification` > `Do not disturb` > `Automatic rules` > `Weeknight`

Activate the rule and press `Do not disturb` to choose if anything should be allowed to get through.

You can choose from:

- Priority only (in the `settings` > `Sound & notification` > `Do not disturb` menu you can configure what is classed as a priority)
- Alarms only
- Total silence

For me this is a really useful feature.

Comment: This wasn't available six years ago when the question was originally asked.

Answer (score 8):

I am surprised nobody has mentioned **Sweet Dreams for Android**. Its a free app and can 
pretty much do everything but tuck you in at night and make eggs and bacon in the morning:

- switch your phone to slient mode automatically during preset times
- those preset silent times can be overridden if your phone detects noise (i.e. you are still awake)
- it has an alarm feature that can wake you up as well

This app was the winner in one of the Android Developer Challenges as well.

More Info:

http://www.androidguys.com/2010/02/11/adc2-winner-sweetdreams-hits-android-market/

Comment: This app hasn't been updated since September 4, 2012. [Sweet Dreams](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inizz&hl=en)

Answer (score 5):

Or... you can use the simplest solution.

1. Add the Power Control widget
2. At night, turn off the Data Sync widget (fourth from the left, between GPS and Light)

No email or other notifications will make noise. In the morning, just turn it back on and you'll get all your notifications.

Comment: This solution prevents you from having a process running all the time just for that :)

Answer (score 4):

You can set the alarm to be active during 'silent mode', but that would eliminate calls.

Also, you can download Tasker or Locale from the market to create custom profiles based on time. These two apps (and I'm sure there are others) are *extremely* customizable and you will be able to set up profiles exactly like you mentioned.

Comment: Too bad Locale is a paid app nowadays

Comment: I use Locale, so if it is during sleep hours, at home, and plugged in, it goes quiet. If I am at work, any time, it goes semi quiet.

Answer (score 3):

Even easier with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en):

Create a profile called ***silentMode***

- Set it to be active between *23:00* until *09:00*
- Now, add a task, call it **muteAudio**, with a tasker's function called '*Silent Mode*', Set that to *On*

That's one profile created. Now to do the opposite logic...

Create another profile called ***normalMode***

- Set it to be active between *09:01* until *22:59*
- Now, add a task call it **soundOn**, with a tasker's function called '*Silent Mode*', set that to *Off*

Now, both tasks will be activated depending on the clock on the device :)

Answer (score 2):

I use [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama&feature=search_result) to achieve this. It is free and very flexible and can control a lot of other settings too. It uses nearby cells to identify your location, so it is not as accurate as others that use GPS, but does not require the GPS to be on in order to achieve location based profiles.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Lollipop you can use "**Downtime and Interuptions**" feature. It lets you define priority interuptions and set the downtime for specific time that you can define for a duration of time. You can also set it as a countdown for one hour or adjust the time by pressing the `+` or the `-` sign. You can access this feature by clicking on the volume rocker button and pressing the corresponding tab to use this feature. You can also access this under `Sound & notification > Interruptions`.

[image: Downtime_lollipop]

<sup>Downtime Feature in Lollipop - [Image Source](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-51-muting-your-lollipop-phone-overnight-just-got-bit-easier)</sup>

If you think that you don't want to be disturbed by anthing not even alarms you can set the interuption to "None" as shown in the above screenshot.

Depending on your device, you can set the following types of notifications as priority:

- Events and reminders.
- Calls from anyone, starred contacts, or any of your contacts (depending on your default phone app).
- Messages from anyone, starred contacts, or any of your contacts (depending on your default messaging app).
- Alarms are always set as priority interruptions. Keep in mind that if you set your notifications to "None" or "Don't interrupt," alarms won't make a sound when they go off. If you need to use an alarm, make sure you allow "All" or "Priority interruptions."

This will be confusing for many Lollipop users. So read anyone of the following links to get to know more about this useful feature.

[Set your notifications - Downtime and Interuptions feature](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6111295?hl=en)

[Master notifications in Android Lollipop with Notification Priority and Downtime](http://www.greenbot.com/article/2854634/master-notifications-in-android-lollipop-with-notification-priority-and-downtime.html)

[How to Manage Interruptions and Downtime in Android 5.0](http://www.howtogeek.com/203716/how-to-manage-interruptions-and-downtime-in-android-5.0/)

[Avoid interruptions and set downtime in Motorola](https://help.motorola.com/hc/3309/50/global/en-us/T1410105705.html)

Answer (score 1):

No widget necessary. I turn off auto sync and turn the volume down to vibrate. I have a sleep tracker app called WakeMate on my phone and the alarm still goes off, even when the volume is turned down to vibrate (using the button on the side, not in settings). To turn off Auto Sync, I press (unselect) the icon that looks like a Refresh symbol on the floating toolbar. If you removed the toolbar, you can turn off auto sync by pressing Settings > Accounts & sync > Auto-sync (clear the check box). It prevents the phone from going to get your email and so on. Turn it back on when you wake up and turn up your volume and you'll soon hear the familiar downloading of emails, text messages, Twitter updates, App updates, whatever.

Answer (score 1):

[Bedside](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.geekherd.bedsidepro2)

Best app. Runs as a clock at night, only thing that will make noise are phone calls. Love it.

Answer (score 0):

Stock sys volume settings:

- Alarm vol up
- Ringer up
- Notifications down
- Sys vol down

You can use Quick Settings to quickly change these settings or Quick Profiles to create profiles for one click profile switching.  I use this last option and have 2 shortcuts on my home, one that turns on my bedtime profile and one that turns on the daytime profile.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is one of the original taskers: 
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cooolmagic.android.toggle5&feature=search_result  (the lite version)

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cooolmagic.android.togglepro&feature=search_result   (Paid version)

Have being using it since Android 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

A new app I've been using is [**Silence**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.epsilonlabs.silence.ads) (Free, but you can [pay to get rid of the ads](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.epsilonlabs.silence)).

It's really pretty simple to set up. You simply add a new event, give it the start and end times, optionally set it to repeat on which days and set your "toggles". It can toggle more than sounds, though:

- Ringer + Notification
- Media
- Alarm
- Airplane Mode
- Wi-Fi
- Bluetooth
- Mobile Data

You can toggle off any or all of those. Another nice feature is that you tell it what to do with the toggle when the event ends:

- Change back (to whatever it was set at before)
- Do nothing
- Silent (for sound toggles)
- Vibrate (for sound toggles)
- Set a volume level (for sound toggles)
- Turn on/off (for system toggles)

I particularly like the "Change back" setting. If I've already silenced the ringer manually, I don't necessarily want it to come back on when the event ends.

They also recently added the ability to tie an event to an event in your calendar.

I use this to set my ringer to vibrate and turn off wi-fi during the times I'm (generally) commuting on the train (because I sit in the Quiet Car and there's no wi-fi available). I also use it to turn off the sound on my tablet during the hours I'm likely to be asleep.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung devices running Jelly Bean have this functionality built in-in the form of Blocking mode, which will allow you to shut off notifications, alarms, incoming calls, and alarms (any or all of the above) for whatever space of time you select.

For the incoming calls (and SMS/email notifications), you can also select whether to block all calls or allow some numbers through.

Comment: But, IIRC, blocking mode also does something weird.  It shows a notification icon 24 hours per day (even during the daytime), I guess to indicate that it is waiting until the nighttime to turn on.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely look at **Sound off Reborn** app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.hubalek.android.apps.soundoff). It works in similar way as scheduled do-not-disturb included in Android 6 but it has nice graphic view of your schedule. It also supports even and odd weeks and what is best: it is completely free. With no ads.

[image: Soud Off Reborn - weekly schedule of don't disturb plan]

Answer (score -2):

'Night clock' free app for Samsung.

Problem solved. Alarm works with phone mute.

Comment: Do include a link to the app on the Play Store.

Comment: There are multiple apps named "Night Clock". Which one did you use? Please link it here.